# How can I auto-correct a simple english sentence programmatically?

Tags: java, spell-checking

When you search google, your search query is autocorrected based on other searches for the same topic (at least I think).  I'm looking for a way to do more or less the same thing, and would just throw a question/query into google, parsing the results; however, I don't think google would be too happy with that.

I've looked at some spell checking libraries, but they don't seem to really give you a good "guess" of what the word should actually be.  Instead they seem to just give you a list of words that each word might be.

Does anybody know of any ways (libraries, etc) I could solve this problem?

Comment: you should specify your technology stack, platform, etc?

Comment: Well, it's a server process that categorizes questions.  I'm working with a large training set of questions and their corresponding categories.  It's all written in Java.  The problem is that the questions involve a large amount of human error.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lucene search engine, and stack of related products like the SOLR server, provide all sorts of functionality to help with this.  Basically, this is done by the search indexing indexing on roots of the words.

There's a lot of meta-data stored and that can be used to feed auto-complete functionality to search boxes that know's about what the related terms are, as well as simply providing you a list of spelling matched autocompletion options.

Lucene is generally seen in the java ecosystem, but it can be used across platforms.

Comment: This would work perfectly if my training data were up to date all of the time, but it doesn't help much for newer topic I wouldn't think.  Still it could be useful to look in to.

Comment: I think you would be suprised how quickly the new data can be indexed . . .

Comment: This seems like it could be quite useful after searching through the documentation a bit.

Comment: @Chris  Awhile back I wrote an introduction to the general concepts of lucene, basic info, but a good orientation to the lucene mindset.  http://zeroinsertionforce.blogspot.com/2008/11/lucene-overview-part-one-creating-index.html

Comment: That is actually pretty helpful. Thanks for all of the help.  Lucene is turning out to be a neat piece of software.